# assertEquals and assertTrue give different results for same variables

Tags: php, phpunit

As tested with phpunit:

```
$xml_1 = new SimpleXMLElement('<name>Bugs</name>');
$xml_2 = new SimpleXMLElement('<name>Bugs</name>');

$this->assertEquals($xml_1, $xml_2);    // Passes
$this->assertTrue($xml_1==$xml_2);      // Fails
```

Um, what?

EDIT:
No, this is not a stupid question.  In Python:

```
import unittest
class TestEqualityIdentity(unittest.TestCase):
def test_equality(self):
    x   =   1
    y   =   1
    self.assertTrue(x==y)       # Passes
    self.assertEqual(x, y)      # Passes
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

No reason PHP need behave like Python.  But, it isn't a stupid question in PHP either.

```
$x = 1;
$y = 1;
$this->assertEquals($x, $y);        //  Passes
$this->assertTrue($x==$y);          //  Passes
```

EDIT 2
Raymond's answer below is right, never mind that at this writing it's 3 votes down.

FWIW, I needed an if test comparison of the text node values of two XML objects, and got it by casting them to strings.

```
$this->assertTrue((string) $xml_1== (string) $xml_2); // Passes, works in if test

// Note that simply referring to a SimpleXMLElement _seems_ to give its 
// text node.  

$this->assertEquals($xml_1, 'Bugs');  // Passes

// This seemed weird to me when I first saw it, and I can't 
// say I like it any better now
```

Comment: I'd be guessing that == tests pointer equality, and assertEquals looks for value equality. But I don't know enough to know for sure. Google should be able to help you here

Comment: Aurelio, thanks for the helpful edit on the title.

Comment: @chernevik You're welcome. Besides... +1 - this is not a stupid question.

Comment: Aurelio, my question edit was made before seeing your comment, the 'stupid question' string isn't a reference to your comment

Comment: Jim, over the past week I've spent at least twenty hours in books and Google trying to figure out how PHP works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 This is a great question.

I had to look in the PHP docs for the answers:  http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/api.html

Equality isn't defined for XML Element objects, so the `$this->assertTrue($xml_1==$xml_2);` will only succeed if the two objects have the same identity (are the same object).

In contrast, *assertEquals* tries to be smart and has special case handling depending on object type.  In the case of XML, it compares the structure and contents of the XML elements, returning True if they have the same semantic meaning eventhough they are distinct objects.

Comment: Thx.  Nice to know it wasn't just me.